# WPF usercontrols on separate tabs: why is radiobutton groupname shared between tabs?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, radio-button, tabcontrol, groupname

I am using a WPF tab control to present separate repeated instances of a user control. i.e. Tab1 for Item1 settings, Tab2 for Item2 settings, and so on.

It appears that the radio button group names are being shared between tabs. What is going on?

Simple example:

A window contains tabs. Each tab contains a user control.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:lib="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <TabControl Margin="0,0,0,100" Name="tabControl1">
        <TabItem Header="tabItem1" Name="tabItem1">
            <lib:UserControl1 x:Name="userControlInTab1" />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="tabItem2" Name="tabItem2">
            <lib:UserControl1 x:Name="userControlInTab2" />
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

The user control is simply two radiobuttons in a group:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Height="50" Width="100">
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton GroupName="Group1" Name="radiobutton1" Content="option1" IsChecked="True" />
    <RadioButton GroupName="Group1" Name="radiobutton2" Content="option2" />
</StackPanel>
```

If you run this app, you will see that only the radiobutton1 in the second tab is checked, despite the usercontrol defining it to always be checked at startup.

Further, setting a radiobutton as checked in code behind seems to uncheck all the radiobuttons in other tabs!

It seems like things behave fine under mouse control (i.e. tabs are independent).

Lastly, the usercontrols do seem to be separate instantiations. I have tried this with sliders on user controls, for example, and they do behave independently across tabs. As they should.

Thanks for anyone's help with this. I have searched widely to no avail. Surely I'm not the only person who has had this issue. I'm using VS2008.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Without the GroupName set it works. It is not strictly necessary since the RadioButtons in one container are automatically grouped anyway. For example:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
Height="50" Width="100">
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <RadioButton  Name="radiobutton1" Content="option1" IsChecked="True" />
            <RadioButton  Name="radiobutton2" Content="option2" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <RadioButton  Name="radiobutton3" Content="option3" IsChecked="True" />
            <RadioButton  Name="radiobutton4" Content="option4" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: The works. Thanks.

So the groupname property seems entirely unnecessary, and you can always separate radiobuttons into containers...

Comment: Exactly. You only would need GroupName if you want to group RadioButtons in the same container. But even then you could put them in an empty Border or similar.

Comment: What if you want two radio buttons under different containers to be in the same group? E.g. you have two radio button in different stack panel (for some reason) but want only one of them to be selected at a time?

Comment: @digitguy in that case you should use the GroupName for the radiobuttons in different containers. If you set the same group name, it will be as if they were in the same container. GroupName is used exactly in the scenario you describe.

Answer (score 7):

This behaviour is by design:

> the whole point of GroupName is to allow you to define radio buttons
>   that act as a group without having to be contained by the same parent
>   panel.

Please read [this article](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2010/11/15/radio-groupname-scope) for detailed explanation.

To speak briefly, there are two solutions for two different cases:

- If you have all logically related radio buttons in one container, then **don't specify a *GroupName***. In this case radio buttons will automatically form a group that's independent of any other radio button groups.
- If you split logically related radio buttons across multiple panels for layout purposes, then [read the article](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2010/11/15/radio-groupname-scope) for a lengthy explanation what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I had a situation where the design did not allow separation of the radios into separate stacks. So, what I did was remove `GroupName` from the xaml and enforce the grouping from the model. This idea came from [this link](http://www.codegain.com/articles/wpf/miscellaneous/how-to-solve-radiobuttons-binding-issue-for-mvvm.aspx), e.g.

```
private bool _useGaugeOpen;
public bool UseGaugeOpen
{
    get { return _useGaugeOpen; }
    set
    {
        _useGaugeOpen = value;
        _useATGOpen = !value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("UseATGOpen");            
    }
}
private bool _useATGOpen;
public bool UseATGOpen
{
    get { return _useATGOpen; }
    set
    {
         _useATGOpen = value;
         _useGaugeOpen = !value;
         RaisePropertyChanged("UseGaugeOpen");
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got my problem fixed by just naming the groups of each set of radio buttons consistently via the XAML properties box under: /Common/GroupName. Now they only interact with the others in the same group.